# How do I Reference a component in navbar on click

Tags: angular, components, navbar

This is the HTML code using Bootstrap classes. I want to display a specific component when I click one of the three elements on the navbar.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-md">
   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">FirstEl</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">SecondEl</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
         <li class="dropdown nav-item ">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link " role="button">Third
               <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li class="dropdown-item">
            <a href="#">Save Data</a>
         </li>
         <li class="dropdown-item">
            <a href="#">Fetch Data</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You have to add routing for your app. please follow this [link](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: or show/hide a component based on the link which is clicked... you're using angularJS or Angular 2+ ?

Comment: I am using Angular 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple project for your understanding [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqkxwt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

You can create a separate file for your routes if you have more routes in your application.

`The Angular Router enables navigation from one view to the next as users perform application tasks.`

It's better to refer [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: I still haven't reached for routes in angular. However, I did it using eventEmitters and  using the *ngIf directive I specified which component will show an event occurs. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at routerLink, here is the documentation : https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

However, you must first have followed this tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5